# Is it possible to train with tensorflow 1 using float16?

Tags: python, tensorflow, precision, keras-rl

Currently train keras on tensorflow model with default setting - float32.

Post training the network is quantized: cast weights to float16. This improves performance by ~x3 while keeping the same accuracy.

I was trying to train from start using float16 and failed miserably. I cannot find any link that explain if that is possible and if not why is it not possible.

Comment: Is `tensorflow1.x` a must? It's getting deprecated kinda fast (e.g. tutorials and docs moved to [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/tree/master/site/en/r1) and are in maintenance mode). If it's not, there is an experimental `keras` policy in `tf2.0` for mixed precision training [explained here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/mixed_precision).

Comment: Most of  the tf 2.0 is experimentally. I have tried the same and failed, probably for reason related to other elements in my network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Automated Mixed Precision](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/mixed-precision-training/index.html#faq-tf) from NVidia might be a way to go.

From what I've gathered since `1.14` it is (was) supported in the upstream. All you would have to do is wrap your optimizer like this:

```
opt = tf.train.experimental.enable_mixed_precision_graph_rewrite(opt)
```

You might also need to set specific `environment variable` from within your Python script, namely:

```
os.environ[‘TF_ENABLE_AUTO_MIXED_PRECISION’] = ‘1’
```

Above should already employ good mixed precision training practices (e.g. loss scaling, keeping `float32` where necessary etc.).

Good resource for this solution should be [official NVidia's documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/sdk/mixed-precision-training/index.html#faq-tf).

Some other resources gathered which also might be useful (though do not seem to indicate you would have to do anything more) [here](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/nvidia-automatic-mixed-precision-tensorflow/), [here](https://medium.com/tensorflow/automatic-mixed-precision-in-tensorflow-for-faster-ai-training-on-nvidia-gpus-6033234b2540) or [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/automatic-mixed-precision).

I would advise against manual casting as you might easily lose precision (e.g. in `BatchNorm` statistics used during inference) unless you know ins-and-outs of specific layers.

Additionally, you might also check `bfloat16` (brain float) type from Google which has `exponent` part of `float32` (`8` bits) and smaller fraction. This allows it to keep greater range of values (e.g. when computing gradients) when compared to `float16` which allows one to avoid `loss scaling`.

Above (`bfloat16`) should be useful mainly in TPUs, AFAIK NVidia GPU's support for it is not too great (someone correct me if I'm wrong). Some information [here](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/bfloat16).

Comment: If it was useful mainly in Google's TPUs then why would NVIDIA make the effort to support it? It can be used with any NVIDIA GPU that supports tensor-cores. V100 and T4 are two of the cards with tensor core support.

Comment: @WilliamD.Irons I meant `bfloat16` format specifically. It's not TPU specific but TPUs is Google's hardware and so is `bfloat16` idea, hence that's where it is supported "out of the box". You can find discussion regarding ideas of `bfloat16` on Intel's CPU and GPU for PyTorch for example, [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/8021), [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/23149) , [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/23509). I'm not sure about current state of it's implementation though.

Comment: @WilliamD.Irons When it comes to Tensor Cores those technologies target `float16` and `int8`, not `bfloat16` AFAIK.

Comment: true, bfloat16 is just for TPUs, but the original question was just float16 :). Overall good answer.